# Redirect when server is down for maintenance and back when up?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, failover

I've got a main production server hosting multiple domains call them site1.com, app.site1.com, and shop.site1.com ( I am using nginx as the web server).

I want to redirect to another domain, say, maintenance.site2.com, when the main production server (site1.com) is down (for maintenance, when i'm staging upgrades, or when something just straight up fails).

I've seen several posts mentioning solutions in this arena for windows based servers, however, I am running all Linux servers on multiple cloud providers (digitalocean and vultr).

Unfortunately, the company i work for uses goDaddy as their registrar and not only is it slow, it's also a bit convoluted when it comes to the documentation. Another note: all of my cloud providers have their own DNS which might aid in this sort of configuration (which i'm not using at the moment out of pure fear that I'll break some unknown goDaddy service that somebody may or may not be using - think LDAP or the like).

I am the only member of my company's "tech" infrastructure and DNS is not my strong suit. Can someone please point me in the direction of the solution i'm looking for? I'm afraid I just don't have the right google keywords to find a solution.

So, my question is exactly this: When my main production server is down, how do I point my DNS to a simple static site on another domain and then once the main domain is active again, point back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Build an `haproxy` box.  This will get you high availability as well as lots of handy statistics.
2. Create a health check in your app.
3. Have haproxy use the health check.
4. Put your two servers in the same backend pool.  The maintenance server should have the `backup` flag so it is only used when the main server is down.
5. Test this using the `hosts` file on some desktop.
6. Point DNS at the `haproxy` box.
7. Then you scan stop worrying about updating DNS all of the time.

Comment: alright! thank you! this is exactly what i need. so i have a dedicated haproxy box that controls it all and i can just configure my dns via the proxy?

Comment: A single haproxy box doesn't give high availability, it creates a single point of failure. You'd probably want two of them.

Comment: @Tim Agreed, but it seems like getting to two app boxes first is more important.  Spinning up a new haproxy on short notice is relatively easy.

Answer (score 3):

DNS Registrar and the DNS service provider can be different. Use AWS Route53 with [failover routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html), which works with AWS servers and other providers servers. It will fail your clients over to the other server when the primary is down. This way you're not paying for an extra server to do routing.

There are other services that do a similar thing - I suspect CloudFlare does too.

Comment: This is really the right solution.